# Cannot Generate Model in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to ROR. I have installed mySql, Ruby, Rubygems and Rails, along with MacPorts. I have project named demo that I am trying to generate model name Movie for. I have also created a database named Movies.

Here is the following error I am receiving when I try to generate a model from Terminal (Mac Lion).

```
rails generate model Movie
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:187:in `stub_source_index170': no such file to load -- rubygems/source_index (LoadError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:353:in `stub_rubygems'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:250:in `replace_entrypoints'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:14:in `setup'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler.rb:116:in `setup'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/setup.rb:7
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
    from /Users/josephcarlson/demo/config/boot.rb:6
    from script/rails:5:in `require'
    from script/rails:5
```

Here is my Gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.11, 3.2.10)
actionpack (3.2.11, 3.2.10)
activemodel (3.2.11, 3.2.10)
activerecord (3.2.11, 3.2.10)
activeresource (3.2.11, 3.2.10)
activesupport (3.2.11, 3.2.10)
akami (1.2.0)
arel (3.0.2)
builder (3.0.4)
bundler (1.2.3)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.4.0)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.4.0)
gyoku (1.0.0)
hike (1.2.1)
httparty (0.9.0)
httpi (2.0.0)
i18n (0.6.1)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (2.1.4)
json (1.7.6)
mail (2.4.4)
mime-types (1.19)
multi_json (1.5.0)
multi_xml (0.5.1)
mysql2 (0.3.11)
nokogiri (1.5.6)
nori (2.0.0)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.4, 1.4.3)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (3.2.11, 3.2.10)
railties (3.2.11, 3.2.10)
rake (10.0.3)
rdoc (3.12)
sass (3.2.5)
sass-rails (3.2.5)
savon (2.0.2)
sprockets (2.2.2)
sqlite3 (1.3.7)
thor (0.16.0)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.12)
tzinfo (0.3.35)
uglifier (1.3.0)
wasabi (3.0.0)

And here is the Gem Env

RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.24
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin11.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-11
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
     - /Users/josephcarlson/.gem/ruby/1.8
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/

### UPDATE

The issue stemmed from an invalid line in the database.yml file. See below.

development:
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf=8
database: test
pool: 5
host: localhost
username: xxxx
passwoord: xxxxxx
socket /tmp/mysql.sock

So as you can see the encoding line and the socket lines were incorrect. I corrected those lines by removing the = in "utf=8" and adding ":" to the socket line. Once fixed I was able to generate models, controllers and/or a scaffolding.

Comment: Have you run `bundle install` yet from your app directory?

Comment: Yes, but I will give it another try.

Comment: It is giving me the same error. Would you like the output of the bundle?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the problem but I always specify columns when I generate a model and you don't have any

Comment: Can you give us the output of `gem list` and `gem env`? Seems like there is something going on with those.

Comment: @jakerella updated the post as instructed. Thanks

Comment: I can't replicate this, and I'm not sure what the issue may be (sorry), but you may want to try upgraded to Ruby 1.9.3 (NOTE: 1.9.1 will NOT work with Rails 3+). Be sure that your environment is properly set up to use the new version and not the old if you do upgrade!